# Django compressor, only compress js

Tags: css, django, internet-explorer, django-compressor

There is an ie7 bug where css selectors in a file [beyond the 4094th selector are ignored](http://demos.telerik.com/testcases/4095issues.html).  How do you disabled django compressor making larger css files from smaller ones, but keep it for javascript?

In settings you can set `COMPRESS_ENABLED = False` which will still [allow for less and other assets to be precompiled offline](http://django-compressor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings/#django.conf.settings.COMPRESS_ENABLED).  Ideally I'd like a COMPRESS_CSS_FILTERS tool [like this for rails](https://github.com/zweilove/css_splitter/blob/master/lib/css_splitter/splitter.rb) ([blog post](http://railslove.com/blog/2013/03/08/overcoming-ies-4096-selector-limit-using-the-css-splitter-gem))

**Edit**

Actually [COMPRESS_CSS_FILTERS just return strings](https://github.com/jezdez/django_compressor/blob/develop/compressor/filters/base.py#L24) so I'd need a post_compress hook (and the one that django compressor provides fires for each of the tag attributes in the {% compress %} blocks, where as one that fires after all the css has been produced would be required).

Comment: Do you want to disable the css compressor for IE7 or for all the browsers?

Comment: @fsouto in the absence of getting a tool similar to the css_splitter for Rails, I think we'd just disable compressor for all browsers to keep it as simple as possible (I've heard that you can configure an IE8 browser to run in "compatibility" mode, i.e. parse css like it was IE7, but can set it's document mode to IE8 (or visa versa), so the server will send IE8 (or IE7) css that will be incorrectly handled, despite the browser asking for it.)